# New Gmail Contacts needs room on left

Tags: gmail-contacts, user-interface

I like the new Gmail Contacts, except for the fact that long group names get cutoff and I can't figure out how to resize things so they fit, as per this image:

[image: Gmail Contacts Cutoff]

Any ideas on how to do this, am I missing something obvious (tried to drag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wife is having similar issues. It looks like they didn't test with a variety of font sizes before releasing it. Have you tried reducing your font size?

It looks like you can still get to the old contacts app by using http://www.google.com/contacts